# How to intercept all the repository classes which has @Repository annotation using spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to intercept all the returning List from my `BaseRepostitary` files. So that i can find the names inside that lists which has to be decrypted using this `decrypt` method. Following is my Aspect Class

```
@Aspect
@Service
public class DecryptionAspect {

 @AfterReturning(value = "execution(java.util.List *(..)) "
        + "&& target(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)) ", returning = "list")
    public void decrypt(List list) throws Exception
    {
        //Do decryption here for the names inside the list
    }

}
```

But the problem is this `decrypt` method is not triggering at the time of my Repository classes gets hit. So something is wrong in my expression. I know i can target the Repository class by the package name. But i have many Repository classes and i have given the `@Repository` annotation for that classes. So i want this AOP expression to identify which are all the classes have `@Repository` annotation present and intercept all the List items inside the Repository classes. So how to rewrite my expression. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it!

```
@AfterReturning(value="execution(* *..*Repository.*(..))",returning="list")
  public void decrypt(List list) throws Exception
    {
        //Do decryption here for the names inside the list
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you could have used `target(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository+)` in order to include subclasses, please note the `+`. This is more type-safe and precise than matching based on class name patterns.

Comment: I am not a Spring user, so I thought that `Repository` was a base class because you used `target()`, which misled me. Now I see it is an annotation used on class level, so it should be `@target()` with a leading `@`.

Answer (score 0):

```
`@Aspect
@Service
public class DecryptionAspect {

 @AfterReturning(value = "execution(java.util.List *(..)) "
        + "&& @target(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)) ", returning = "list")
    public void decrypt(List list) throws Exception
    {
        //Do decryption here for the names inside the list
    }

}`
```

you should use `@target` to match the target class with a specific annotation.

Does the BaseRepostitary class implements some interface?

I Try this.Hope that works.

```
@Aspect
@Service
public class TestAop {
  @AfterReturning(value = "execution( java.util.List *.queryList*(..)) "
        + " && @target(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)",           returning  = "list")
public void decrypt(List list) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("test........."+ list.toString());
    //Do decryption here for the names inside the list
}
```

}

ServiceImpl:

```
 @Repository
 public class ServiceImpl  implements IService {
   @Override
 public <T> List<T> queryList(Map<String, Object> paramMap, Class<T> clazz) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: It is throwing some error. Can you post how the exact expression would be.

Comment: Yes its implements interface

Comment: the methods you attempt to intercepting is implements from interface? If not,maybe cannot be intercepting.PS:which version of spring do you use?

Comment: Yes the methods i attempt to intercept extends BaseRepository and implements interface. I am using spring 3.

Comment: I try that local.The method implements from interface can be intercepted.If the method is implement in super class,you should override it in subclass.You can try this.PS:note that Repository is a annotation from spring ,and it can not Inherited.Also if the subclass extend from super class and implements interface. the method implements from interface can be intercepted.I guess the reason is:Spring use Jdk dynamic proxies as default If a subclass implements from a interface.

Comment: Maybe you can try it.If not,Please tell me.

Comment: I dont get you. Please help!

Comment: I don't understand why you targeted service. I want to intercept all the lists in the Repository classes only.

Comment: You can Change to Repository.

Comment: I am Sorry, then I can't help.