# Injecting JpaRepository<User> directly

Tags: java, spring

Im looking for a way intercept all requests going to all the **defined** methods.

> (defined=whatever is on the JpaRepository interface).

so for example when someone calls repo.findAll() I will be able to run a generic code before and after.

> (generic=same code of all the entities).

So what I did is created a generic class and implemented methods in JpaRepository and then intercept all the requests.

```
@Repository
public class BaseJpaRepository<T> implements JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<T, Long> repository;

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        //run some code here
        List<T> res = repository.findAll();
        //run some code here
        return res;
    }
    // all other methods here...
}
```

this is the interface to inject into services:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

}
```

this is the Bean

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryBean extends  BaseJpaRepository<User> implements JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

The problem is that `private JpaRepository<T, Long> repository;` is not injecting, I assume that this is because spring needs the Entity type in bootstrap time.

I also tried to inject explicit type it to the constructor if `UserRepositoryBean` and pass it to the parent.  but its unsatisfied.

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryBean extends  BaseJpaRepository<User> implements JpaRepository<User, Long> {

public UserRepositoryBean(JpaRepositry<User, Long> repo){super(repo);}

}
```

Any way to intercept all the Spring jpa methods?

Thanks

Comment: `is not injecting`. What's the error/exception produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you define basic interface that all your custom repositories will be inherited from

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseJpaRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
     // You can also declare any generic methods here, 
     // and override (intercept) them in BaseJpaRepositoryImpl as well
}
```

And it's implementation as well

```
@NoRepositoryBean
class BaseJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements BaseJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    public BaseJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager em) {
        super(entityInformation, em);
    }

    // One of 'defined' methods inherited from SimpleJpaRepository (and in turn from JpaRepository)
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        //run some code here
        List<T> res = super.findAll();
        //run some code here
        return res;
    }

    // other 'defined' methods to intercept ...
}
```

Your custom repository would then look just as usual except that it is now derived from your `BaseJpaRepository` interface instead of Spring's `JpaRepository`

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository extends BaseJpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

To make it all work, let's modify following annotation that is usually placed onto some `@Configuration` class or onto `@SpringBootApplication`-ed class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"org.example.repositories"},
        repositoryBaseClass = BaseJpaRepositoryImpl.class
)
```

**P.S.** Another viable approach is to use [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html). You can also check out similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595189/how-to-intercept-all-the-repository-classes-which-has-repository-annotation-usi)

Comment: Thank you. its working, but is it possible to expose only my methods and not the entire simple jpa methods? thanks

Comment: @SexyMF yes. You can remove `extends JpaRepository<T, ID>` from `BaseJpaRepository` and remove `extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>` from `BaseJpaRepositoryImpl`. However you loose ability to use methods of  `JpaRepository` like `findById`, `findAll`, etc. So it's a pointless move, I think